# Keep Source Formatting after Sheets Split

Tags: excel, vba, format

Please can someone tell me how to keep the source format for the files created using the below macro. When I open the new files the colours have all changed compared to the original and I need these to match.

```
Sub SaveSheets()

    ' Save sheets as seperate workbooks
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+W

    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim sht As Object    'Could be chart, worksheet, Excel 4.0 macro,etc.
    Dim strSavePath As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    'Don't show any screen movement

    strSavePath = "C:\Users\Joe Bloggs\Documents\Save Sheets\" 'Change this to suit your needs

    Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each sht In wbSource.Sheets
        sht.Copy
        Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook
        wbDest.SaveAs (strSavePath & sht.Name)
        wbDest.Close    'Remove this if you don't want each book closed after saving.
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:    'Just in case something hideous happens
    MsgBox "An error has occurred. Error number=" & Err.Number & ". Error description=" & Err.Description & "."

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the colors manually set or determined by conditional formatting?

Comment: The original report is produced using Report Builder 2.0 and exported to excel. When opening the report the colours are correct but when using this macro to split the different tabs into individual files the colours don't stay the same.

Comment: Are you saving the file first?

Comment: Or export right to this macro?

Comment: So I export from report builder 2.0 which in affect save this as a excel document. Then I open this file and use the macro to split the multiple report sheets into individual files

Comment: I can’t replicate on my end. I formatted a sheet and could move it without losing formats. Could be related go the report builder idk. I’ll remove my solution to not deter others from opening your post. I would add my solution as an attempt on your post so others don’t tell you the same thing :)

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look.

Comment: I think you are correct it is something to do with report builder. I have just noticed though if i open a new sheet and copy and paste specials "keeping original formatting" the colours move over. Could this be wrote into the Macro?

Comment: You can manually copy and paste instead of moving worksheets. More code to write but may be what you need to do given the 3rd party app

Comment: Is this something you could help with? This is all a little over my head.

Comment: Sure. Give some details on your data layout. How many columns? Are columns fixed? How many rows, are rows fixed?

Comment: Oh great news - Instead of describing the layout is there a way of me maybe sending you a copy of the template file?